# Обращение к переменной до ее инициализации

Tags: javascript

Совсем детский вопрос, но не могу разобраться. Браузер ругается на последнюю строчку can't access lexical declaration 'date' before initialization, хотя переменная date уже объявлена. В чем может быть причина?

```js
let date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() - 14);
for (let i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
}
```

```js
let dateArray = [];
let date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() - 14);
for (let i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
  let day = date.getDate();
  let month = date.getMonth();
  let year = date.getyear();
  let date = `${day}-${month}-${year}`;
  dateArray.push(date);
}
```

Comment: неправда. ошибка в другом месте

Comment: либо это не весь код

Comment: добавь весь код в вопрос нажав "Править"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это известный баг в английском языке. В нем очень мало слов.

```
{
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);      <---
  ...
  let date = `${day}-${month}-${year}`;  <---
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, как же я этого мог не заметить

Comment: @AleksanderShevelev Пожалуйста. Успехов.